# How to run an If statement >between< other If statements in clean way

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, c#-6.0, col

This is the If statment I want to be able to run between all other If statements.
It controls if the index of a two dimensional array has the value of 9. IF it does then it should be reset to a value of 0.

```
if (numbers[row, col] == 9)
{
     numbers[row, col] = 0;
}
```

Basically, no value should ever get above 9 in value.

The code below is where I want to use the above if statement to control this.

```
// These are the "other" IF statements.
    if (row < 9 && col <= 9)
    {
        numbers[row + 1, col] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row > 0 && col <= 9)
    {
        numbers[row - 1, col] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row >= 0 && col < 9)
    {
        numbers[row, col + 1] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row >= 0 && col > 0)
    {
        numbers[row, col - 1] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row < 9 && col > 0)
    {
        numbers[row + 1, col - 1] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row < 9 && col < 9)
    {
        numbers[row + 1, col + 1] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row > 0 && col > 0)
    {
        numbers[row - 1, col - 1] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
    if (row > 0 && col < 9)
    {
        numbers[row - 1, col + 1] += 1;
    }
    //RUN IF STATEMENT HERE
```

Comment: What are you doing here?  Is this a Game of Life thing?  Because they are better ways to do this.

Comment: Are you just trying to increment the value of all points around a current point in a 3x3 grid (current point is the centre)? Wouldn't the clean approach be to use a loop?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama
Yes this is the case, a loop might be better in this case. Did not think of it at first. 
Am a beginner you see.

Comment: If you want to keep the code structure as it is, move a copy of the if statement limiting the value (adjusting the indexes) to inside the outer if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your array is has two dimensions, use a two-level, nested loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.GetLength(0); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < numbers.GetLength(1); j++)
        if (numbers[i, j] >= 9)
            numbers[i, j] = 0;
```